# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, visual-studio, cmder

```
const $ = require ('cheerio');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const url = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda";


function extractionBrut(url){
    return fetch(url)
           .then((reponse) => reponse.text())
           .then((data) => {
               return data;
           })
}

const getFormationList = async () => {
    const data = await extractionBrut(url);

    const num = $.parseHTML(data).length;
    console.log(num);
    for(let i = 0; i<num; i++){
        const numTable = $('<div id="" class="bandeau-container homonymie plainlinks hatnote" style="">')[i];
        console.log(numTable);
    }
}
getFormationList();
```

I want to show the different section of this div however i have this error and don't know how to solve it.

Comment: In your `extractBrut` function, you can't get the value of a promise outside of it. Try returning a promise or callback.

Comment: @code - They're using `$.parseHTML()` described [here](https://cheerio.js.org/modules.html#parsehtml).  I'm not sure they are using it correctly, but you can call `$.parseHTML(someHTML)` and get back a pseudo-DOM.

Comment: What line number was your error on?

Comment: My line of error is during the for loop

Answer (score 0):

The `$` is supposed to be loaded with data. You would do something like:

```js
const cheerio = require ('cheerio');
```

And later:

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(someHtmlThatYouGotFromNodeFetch);
```

Now you can use the `$` as if it's jQuery, or how does cheerio know what HTML you're working with?

Comment: I wanted to extract data from html web pages and display in my terminal a part of this page in table form by using cheerio

Comment: First, i extract the HTML data with the url variable, then i choose which section i want to display with num and last i display the occurrence of this div section

Comment: @bigbenkei instead of parseHTML can you use `cheerio.load()`? Thta's the traditional way to do it... and it's always worked for me

Comment: @bigbenkei that's great! Could you select my answer as correct?